# How to get directory from filepath in QGIS action

Tags: qgis, expression, field-calculator

I have in QGIS layer that contains filepath (e.g. `D:/file/28238/pic/D4D3-06_1.png`) and I would like to get directory path only like `D:/file/new/28238/pic`.

Is it possible to do by expression in field calculator?

Answer (score 5):

There is no builtin function in QGIS field calculator that can do your task, but luckily you can create custom function in QGIS using Function Editor in field calculator, please follow the steps below

1. Open your shapefile in QGIS.
2. Open Attribute Table and click field calculator.
3. Please check the box saying Update existing field and select your desired field.
4. Then go to Function Editor tab click new file and name it splitLast as shown in figure
   [image]
5. Repalce the existing code with code shown below

   ```
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *

   @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
   def splitLast(splitStr,splitVal,feature,parent):
      return splitVal.join(splitStr.split(splitVal)[0:-1])
   ```
6. click the load button and restart your QGIS now again open the field calculator and you will be able to see your splitLast function in custom list as shown in figure below

[image]

7. Now add the following expression in expression tab and click ok and you are done.

   ```
   splitLast("rqewr",'/')
   ```

**Note:Here "rqewr" is the name of field in which "D:/file/28238/pic/D4D3-06_1.png" is stored you can also pass this string instead of field name to function.**

Good Luck

Comment: Cheers Asad! I have also do it by python

Comment: or more pythonic in a qgsfunction: from pathlib import Path Path('D:/file/28238/pic/D4D3-06_1.png').parent

Answer (score 1):

While waiting I have done it using python:

```
import os
path=os.path.dirname ("[% "FILEPATH" %]")
os.startfile (path)
```

Maybe someone will use it...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: or use pathlib module instead of os module: https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/